# How to fix Controls positions after Form Maximize

Tags: c#, location, picturebox

How to keep PictureBoxes in the same location after i maximize the Form? I set the Anchor property to none but PictureBoxes still move after Form maximization.

Comment: Set anchors to Left|Top  (which is the default anyway)!  - Of course a 'fixed position' is not a well defined goal.. Do you want the absolute location to stay fixed or a relative position (e.g. centered) ??

Comment: I want it to stay fixed

Comment: So set anchors to Left|Top as I just told you !

Comment: No i means i want it relative sorry

Comment: Then remove the anchors. an anchor keeps the distance from control border to container border fixed. Removing all anchors makes the control float in a the relative position. If it was centered it will stay centered. If it was at 25%,25% it will stay so. This mean that it will move in absolute coordinates.